# dtruss not working on my machine?

Tags: macos, operating-systems

I am fairly new to Mac OSX. I need to examine some system calls, and apparently dtruss is a good tool for doing that.
However, I think dtruss is not really working.
When I execute

```
sudo dtruss -a -f ls -l
```

what I get is simply the output of ls -l, and then the header of what it should be the table with the system calls. This seems to be empty:

```
PID/THRD  RELATIVE  ELAPSD    CPU SYSCALL(args)          = return

CALL                                        COUNT
```

Why is dtruss not working on my system? I have High Sierra. I have disabled the system integrity protection (csrutil status returns System Integrity Protection status: disabled).

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the machine solved this. Not sure why.